# What is the fastest way to insert value into array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to insert some values into a array. My method took a while and it is not faster

```
    let activity= {} as IActivity;
    activity.firstValue=this.firstValue;
    activity.secondtValue=this.secondValue;
    activity.thirdValue=this.thirdValue;
    activity.fourthValue= this.fourthValue;
this.listOActivity = [] as IActivity[];
 this.listOfDocument.unshift(activity);
```

the html:

```
 <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="firstValue"></input>
 <ion-input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="secondValue"></ion-input>
 <ion-input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="thirdValue"></ion-input>
 <ion-input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="fourthValue"></ion-input>
```

Is there another solution that can be faster?

Comment: By faster, do you mean more syntactically condensed, or with higher performance?

Comment: Where is the array?

Comment: I can't really see the array you are talking about?

Comment: @Andreas Christiansen with higher performance

Comment: check the update please

Comment: Any real problem with your current code?

Comment: yes it tooks from 1 s to 2 second to add the object into my array.

Comment: I don't think your example carries enough information from your actual scenario. By looking at your example code, nothing indicates a 2 second performance hit. For example, `this.listOfDocument` is not declared, `this.listOActivity` is never used, and `activity` is never added to `this.listOfDocument`. You need to provide more information if you want a helpful answer.